# customizing bootstrap 3 less project structure questions

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, project-structure

I have read the following article that describes a nice Bootstrap Less project structure that allows customizing bootstrap without editing source code. But it is for Bootstrap 2 I guess:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/12/customizing-bootstrap/.

I really like this article that suggests the following structure for less files.

1) Create your own `theme.less` on top of Bootstrap files

2) Include into your fresh theme.less the following:

```
 // importing all bootstrap.less files, leve them untouched, so you can update bootstrap
 @import “../bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less”;

 // this is copy of bootstrap variables.less with custom color scheme and other customizations
 @import “custom-variables.less”;

 // your own overrides anc custom classes
 @import “custom-other.less”;

 // utilities as the last
 @import “../bootstrap/less/utilities.less”;
```

But as I am new to Bootstrap and Less, I am not sure that this fits Bootstrap 3 for 100%.

1) My questions is whether this project structure fits Bootstrap 3?

2) I do not get why `utilities.less` should be reimported as the last file (as it is already imported into core bootstrap: bootstrap.less first time and then second time in theme.less )?

3) Bootstrap 2 had `responsive.less` file together with `bootstrap.less`. In Bootstrap 2 I had to include `responsive.less` seperatly, but in Bootstrap 3 not. However, there is `responsive-utilities.less`, should I include it as the last file after `utilities.less`?

Comment: Are those smart quotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1) My questions is whether this project structure fits Bootstrap 3?

Not exactly, you need to change some file names and stop importing `utilities.less`

#### 2) I do not get why `utilities.less` should be re imported as the last file (as it is already imported into core bootstrap: bootstrap.less first time and then second time in theme.less)?

In Bootstrap 2.X this make sense, since you could use the function, mixins and variables defined there

#### 3) Bootstrap 2 had responsive.less file together with bootstrap.less. In Bootstrap 2 I had to include responsive.less seperatly, but in Bootstrap 3 not. However, there is responsive-utilities.less, should I include it as the last file after utilities.less?

No, in Bootstrap 3 you don't need to import `responsive-utilities.less`, as is imported by `bootstrap.less` and is mobile-first by default.

This is the structure I use for BS3:

```
@import "../bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "variables.less";

//Here start customization and I can use my variables defined in @variables.less
@media (min-width: @screen-lg) {
    width: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But as I am new to Bootstrap and Less, I am not sure that this fits Bootstrap 3 for 100%.

Foremost, Bootstrap is a framework in itself, you don't create it, but you use it and make changes or add changes as per your need. Bootstrap 3 is built ground up and is different from Bootstrap 2 in some ways. You may want to clone/fork bootstrap to modify according to your need. You can read about [customizing Bootstrap3](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#customizing). Although, IMO customizing v2 or v3 would largely be similar. Read [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952571/how-has-twitter-bootstrap-3-changed-over-version-2-3-2) to understand primary difference between the two versions.

> 1) My questions is whether this project structure fits Bootstrap 3?

The structure and order of inclusion of less files can be found in [Github Source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less) If you wish to customize it, you can append reference to your less file. That way you would have your changes included in the generated bootstrap CSS.

> 2) I do not get why utilities.less should be reimported as the last file (as it is already imported into bootstrap.less)?

From the source code(link reference above), I see that its included only once.

> 3) Bootstrap 2 had responsive.less file together with bootstrap.less. In Bootstrap 2 I had to include responsive.less seperatly, but in Bootstrap 3 not.

Bootstrap 3 is based on Mobile first approach, which implies that it is responsive by default. While in the case Bootstrap 2, one is required to include responsive CSS if needed.

> However, there is responsive-utilities.less, should I include it as the last file after utilities.less?

IMO you should be fine without changing anything here, let it it be as is and include your customization at the end.

Comment: The whole my question is about customizing. utility.less is included twice, because it is already references here  @import “../bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less”; (and this is also written in the article I linked). I am not asking about if given structure fits also Bootstap 3 for customizing.

Comment: @renathy: I'm sure one of your questions says *whether this project structure fits Bootstrap 3?*